# Npm install/run dev fails for not finding Git Bash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, git-bash, nodemon

I have a Javascript project set using React.js. Npm install for nodemon package version 2.0.7 fails with following errors:

[image: Error log]

It seems that the installation is trying to spawn Git Bash but without success.
Should the installation spawn bash.exe from the folder C:\Program Files\Git\bin instead
of C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Git\Git Bash?

Same error message happens when running npm run dev to start the Node server:
[image: npm run dev errors]

Same errors happen when run from Git Bash.

Earlier nodemon version 1.10.0 installation succeeds with no errors.

I have

OS Windows 10

npm version 6.14.8

node version 14.15.0

git version 2.28.0.windows.1

I think my Git is set to environment path variable correctly.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: The error states that it can't run that postinstall script, but if you look at [what that script does](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/bin/postinstall.js), all it does is post a CTA asking you to donate to the project. Looking at the line `node bin/postinstall || exit 0`, it's meant to fail peacefully but isn't. You can just ignore it.

Comment: Note that git-bash has nothing to do with Git other than being included in Git distributions (because Git needs a shell, and git-bash is a port of a shell that works for Git). The [tag:git] tag is inappropriate here. There is a [tag:git-bash] tag that you could add, perhaps.

Comment: I updated the npm run dev part of the post and added an image. 
The same errors seem to happen also in this case. 
The nodemon-command is not recognised in the command line after npm install. nodemon.js is missing from the nodejs\node_modules folder.

Comment: Are you using any firewall which is blocking the execution? Please verify

Comment: @ShubhraKushal I tried to start the server with firewall set off. The result was still the same.